# How to export env variables as another user

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, environment-variables

I'm trying to set an environment variable for a user session before running a script:

```
su - myUser -c "export myVar=$toto ; sh scriptThatNeedsMyVar.sh"
```

The scripts fails, I tried to debug and print myVar value:

```
su - myUser -c "export myVar=$toto ; echo $myVar"
```

returns nothing, that means that my env variable wasn't created although I'm  creating and printing it in the same bash !
Then when I login as `myUser`and type each command in bash console it works well

```
$su - myUser
$export myVar=toto
$echo $myVar
toto
```

I'm I missing something ?
Why is this happening and how can I export a temporary variable as another user ( I'm not allowed to edit bashrc or any other system file)

Comment: Your echo works if you put the command in single quotes to prevent Bash from expanding the variable before running the command: `su - myUser -c 'export myVar=toto ; echo $myVar'`. No idea about the script file, that is probably a different issue.

Comment: Actually myVar should be expanded as it should contains another variabIe value I've edited my question ..

Comment: Oh, missed that. But then you still may not have the `echo $myvar` within the double quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `env`:

```
su - myUser -c "env myVar=\"$toto\" scriptThatNeedsMyVar.sh"
```

Assuming, of course, that `scriptThatNeedsMyVar.sh` is executable, and findable in `myUser`'s `PATH`, and begins with `#!/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 4):

As [Byte Commander explained](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033217/how-to-export-env-variables-as-another-user/1033225#comment1680470_1033217), you have to put the command in single quotes to prevent Bash from expanding the variable. If `$toto` has to be expanded in the original shell, provide it as an argument outside the command list and access it as `$0`:

```
su - myUser -c 'export myVar="$0"; echo $myVar' "$toto"
```